# .htaccess domain redirection to folder but preventing direct access with 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have a shared hosting in which I want to host several websites. To this end, and to keep things clear, I have redirected my primary domain (i.e. www.mydomain.com) to a folder (i.e. /mydomain.com/). However, I want to prevent direct access to this folder (www.mydomain.com/mydomain.com/) from the URL with a 404 error (not found).

This is the .htaccess in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain.com/0.1/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain.com/0.1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mydomain.com/0.1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}% ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /mydomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

And this is the .htaccess in /mydomain/ with a bunch of rules for nice and tidy URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/(.+) index.php?a=about&b=$1
RewriteRule ^services/(.+) index.php?a=services&b=$1
```

Right now this is the result:

Accessing www.mydomain.com shows the content in /mydomain/ as hoped. However, www.mydomain.com/mydomain/ is also displayed, ignoring the 404 rule, and creating another folder -whatever the name- without an htaccess DOES throw the 404.

I've been dealing with this problem for 5 days now and tried everything. At this point I don't know if the error comes from the root .htaccess or the folder's.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Just to be clear, I have no control over the httpd.conf file.

---

Notes:

1. I forgot saying that there is an additional folder inside /mydomain.com/ called /0.1/ for version control.
2. If a include "RewriteOptions Inherit" after "RewriteEngine On" in the /mydomain.com/0.1/ htaccess, I get a 500 internal server error.
3. Deleting the /mydomain.com/0.1/ htaccess file altogether will produce the desired 404 error for www.mydomain.com/mydomain.com/0.1/ and produce a 505 in www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

The `R` flag in rewrite rule should be something between 301 to 399 , so it can not be 404!!! 
your rule should be like below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}    ^/mydomain\.com/? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  throw_404.php [L]
```

create `throw_404.php` and to send 404 status code! and add `L` flag to your first rule for avoiding conflicting between that rule and mine!

Comment: It isn't working. Just to be sure: I placed the throw_404.php file in /domain.com/ with a single line <?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>.

Comment: About [R=404], 404 errors have been successfully sent for the rest of folders and files...weird.

Comment: @4dllmg put **throw_404.php** in root folder not in **/domain.com/**

Comment: @4dllmg I know it sends 404 not found response code, but because in its manual says it should be something between 301 to 399, so I said that. anyway your rewrite rule had problem :-D

Comment: @4dllmg for second **.htaccess** file: post content of both file here to find the problem!

Comment: Both .htaccess are in the original post. The throw_404.php solution is not working. Bear in mind that the 404 part of the htaccess might not be the problem at all. Maybe there is a conflict with previous htaccess statements.